# Can I identify user by in-app-purchase transaction id?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store

I build an ios/android (react-native) app, that doesn't require authentication. The only reason I want to identify users is to backup and restore their data in case they have to reinstall the app or something.

It's acceptable to have backups only for subscribers. Can I use in-app-purchase TransactionId to reliably identify users? I've seen people complaining about transaction id getting changed illogically. Is that true? Are there any other ways to identify user?

Answer (score 0):

original_transaction_id is the closest thing to a stable identifier you can get and appears in every transaction. However it is not permanent, and will change is a user changes storefront, or if they are unsubscribed for 6 months, or if they subscribe to a product in another subscription group.